When using Selenium's takeScreenshot() on a select dropdown, the captured screenshot has an offset,
Screenshot
When using Selenium's takeScreenshot() on a select dropdown, the captured screenshot has an offset, causing it to be aligned to the bottom with a gap.
  let screenshot = await driver.takeScreenshot();
here is the default takeScreenshot() provided by driver to take screenshots
I was taking a screenshot of a dropdown,
the dropdown items were listed with a offset
